# Can't find workspace outside of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

I checked the `src` folder (inside the same folder that I have my eclipse folder in) to make sure all the class files were there. There were none, in fact it looked completely different and out of sync from my project.

Is there some other folder or place where eclipse keeps my code ?

By the way, I use `Mac`. Also, don't think it should be a problem but I keep my eclipse application on a flash drive (the actual install location for `eclipse` is on my computer, though).

Comment: RightClick (on project) -> Properties -> Find Location. And your code is saved in workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your code base in eclipse & select properties. In the properties tab you will find the disc location of your project.

Answer (score 1):

When you first setup eclipse you are asked to choose a `workspace`.  The `workspace` is where your code is saved.  If you right click on your project and click properties, in the resource section there is a spot labeled `Location:` The file path there is where that project is saved. (It will be under your `workspace` folder)